# Is low self esteem pushing person toward maximizing (instead of being easily satisfied)

Tags: cognitive-psychology, social-psychology, personality

See the answer to this question: [Is there a term that describes the personality trait of always desiring more?](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/a/7691/4425)

> Schwartz and colleagues (2002) have proposed that people fall into two
>   groups: those who seek to maximize their decision by finding the very
>   best option out of choices presented (maximizers), and those who have
>   an idea in mind of what would be an "acceptable" option and settle for
>   the first choice that surpasses their expectations (satisficers).
>   Maximizers are always on the look out for "the best," are less
>   satisfied with their choices, more likely to "socially compare" their
>   options to others, and more likely to experience regret (Ma & Roese,
>   2014). Another recent publication proposed that when individuals
>   experience "choice closure," and stop re-evaluating the non-selected
>   alternative options, satisfaction with choice can increase (Gu, Botti,
>   & Farro, 2013).

Is it possible to state that looking for challenges and being a maximizer can be correlated to a low selfesteem?

Comment: Care to elaborate on why you formulate that hypothesis?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be indeed some correlation between maximization and self-esteem (as can be seen even in the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximization_%28psychology%29)). However it doesn't necessarily predicts low self-esteem.

Quoted from wikipedia:

> Initial research on maximizing showed uniformly negative outcomes
>   associated with chronic maximizing tendencies. Such tendencies were
>   associated with lower happiness, self-esteem, and life
>   satisfaction;[2](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/dont-delay/200804/what-flavor-perfectionist-are-you-it-matters) with greater depression and regret;[2](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/dont-delay/200804/what-flavor-perfectionist-are-you-it-matters) with lower
>   satisfaction with choices;[8][9] with greater perfectionism;[3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectionism_%28psychology%29)[10]
>   and with greater decision-making confusion, commitment anxiety, and
>   rumination ... However, as disagreement over the definition of maximizing 
>   grew, research began to show diverging effects: some negative, some
>   neutral, and some positive

Interestingly, those results closely resembles studies regarding correlation between ["perfectionism"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfectionism_%28psychology%29) and "self-esteem" (perfectionism being a similar concept to maximization which you described).

There have been many studies, but in general, perfectionism can be detrimental only when it's maladaptive/ neurotic. On the other hand, positive/adaptive perfectionism tend to correlate with positive emotions, which can factors in a more positive self-esteem.

Some studies further classified that perfectionism coming from one-self is associated with adaptive aspect of perfectionism, and thus more related to positive emotions. While perfectionism that comes form social environment (imposed/prescribed by others), is more associated to the maladaptive aspect. As discussed in this [article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/dont-delay/200804/what-flavor-perfectionist-are-you-it-matters).

It somewhat make senses considering the definition of ["self-esteem"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-esteem). In general, self-esteem is defined as how we evaluate our own worth, which starts early in infancy. It affected by many factors which may changes across lifetime (for example in [childhood](http://www.phac-aspc.gc.ca/hp-ps/dca-dea/publications/ffc-ief/book-livre-5-eng.php) and [teens](http://understandingteenagers.com.au/blog/teenagers-and-self-esteem-key-factors/)), but in general it's largely affected by social factors.

So in summary, it's possible that being a maximizer (or being perfectionist in general) correlated to low-self esteem. But it depends on how exactly the maximizing is.